# How to add Gutenberg block via custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have custom theme and I want to add custom Gutenberg block, multiple of them in the future. Something seems to be missing, as I can't find registered block in editor, even though it is registered without any errors and can be seen with:

```
$block_types = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();
var_dump($block_types);
```

I've copied code generated by [WordPress Create Block Tool](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) to my theme. It is working perfectly well as a plugin, but same code run from the theme, doesn't work properly.


Temporarely I have strure like that:
[image: block code structure]

Inside example-block.php I have this:

```
function learning_palace_example_block_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'learning_palace_example_block_block_init' );
```

example-block.php is called from function.php like that:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/blocks/example-block/example-block.php');
```

I've tried also other setups, like registering block straight from functions.php, but to no avail, always block is missing from Gutenberg editor.

Comment: When you are testing the block from the theme, have you disabled/removed the plugin that contains the same block/same function name?